# I mistakenly deleted a file from project navigator and now xcode say no schemes on top left

Tags: swift, xcode, swift2, delete-file

I am new to swift and I was undoing a bunch of stuff on Main.storyboard. However, I accidentally deleted something from project navigator. Now xcode says no schemes. When I try to manage schemes, I cant find original project name. I cant even run my project. I am so lost, someone please help me recover my previous work.[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

1. right click CurryFinder.xcodeproj -> delete -> Remove Reference
2. click '+' at the down left corner of xcode -> add files -> select CurryFinder.xcodeproj add it again